# dask dataframe memory issue on large file

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

```
a = dd.read_csv('huge.csv', blocksize=1e6)
g = a.groupby(['col_a', 'col_b'])
g.col_c.sum().max().compute()  # failed, MemoryError
```

I thought `dask.dataframe` won't fail on memory issues, but what?
BTW, `blocksize` matters I think, what if I set a very small size, say 1e3, the `read_csv` takes forever to finish....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groupby-aggregations by default reduce into a single partition.  If your result has many groups then this single partition may be very large.  You might consider setting the `split_out=` keyword to groupby.sum to some moderate number, like 10.

```
g.col_c.sum(split_out=10).max().compute()
```

This will cause the groupby-aggregation result to be split among ten partitions rather than a single partition.

I don't know if this is actually your problem though, if this doesn't work then I recommend creating a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Also, you probably want a larger blocksize.  1MB blocks are very small.  I would shoot for 10-100x that, or, better yet, leave it as the default value.